# Hide Keyboard with onFocus event

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I know it sounds a bit confusing, but I have an angular app that is supposed to run only on a mobile device with a barcode reader that automatically writes what it reads inside the focused input field.
I setted the app so that when the page is loaded my input field has focus and I want that the soft keyboard to be invisible so the user cannot manually write in this field.

The flow should seem like this: input -> autofocus -> (onFocus)="hideKeyboard()"

Autofocus is a custom directive that sets the dom element to be the focus in ngOnInit.

Thanks in advance for any tip.

Comment: Why is there an input field if user shouldn't be able to input ? Make the field a variable that simply displays the barcode.

Comment: Because the field must be filled with what is read by the barcode reader that is a hardware feature that automatically writes the content inside the focused field, that's not a behaviour that I control. 
I don't want the user to be able to modify it but just hit the hardware button that starts the scan and then he hits a disabled button to say "ok". I want it like this so that the human user cannot accidentally press a key and modify the barcode content before hitting "ok".

Comment: you can make that field read only or disabled.

Comment: readonly doesn't let me edit it, and disabled does not hide the keyboard.

Comment: if you put `<input (keydown)="onKeydown($event)">` event, the button click enters on it? If not, you could prevent all keys pressed

Comment: @Gaspar I tried your idea but the input I get from the hardware triggers the keydown event but it has no key associated so it doesn't work. I tried to "hide" the input field and just make appear a paragraph with what's been inserted behind the scene but the keyboard's still there.

Comment: I tried setting the display css attribute to none, but it prevents the input from getting values. 
I tried setting visibility to hidden and I had the same result.
I tried setting opacity to 0 and it did hide and received values but the keyboard was still there and if a user touches where the input is supposed to be it can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

There's a start here in [this project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kodxfi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), but when you click outside of the input (in the button) lose focus and the keyboard is hidden again. But yet, it's a start...

Comment: That's interesting to prevent the keep the focus on the input field since it is required in order to proceed with the other form fields. If the field loses focus the whole work would be lost.
Thanks for sharing!!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
    <input id="id1" class="hidekeyboard"/>


    $('#id1').<input_type>({
    /* options */
    });

    $('.hidekeyboard').on('focus',function(){
    $(this).trigger('blur');
    });
```